# Kiosk mode guest session under gdm3

Tags: gnome, guest-session

How can we create a kiosk mode guest session under gdm3 going forward from Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: I would use a kiosk specific distro http://tuxdiary.com/2014/11/05/linux-distros-for-kiosks/ . Why try to re-invent the wheel ? A kisok distro will be more secure and easier to deploy.

Comment: The guest session feature is said to be [added to GDM 3 by Ubuntu 18.04](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2017-June/004999.html).

Comment: That would be awesome. Thanks for the post Gunnar.

Answer (score 1):

Now that Ubuntu 17.10 onward Gnome is going to be default ans those of us who have gotten used to the guest session feature in lightdm unity-greeter. There is a solution as described here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258544/create-guest-account-in-gnome-3-x-on-arch-linux

Note: changed gdm to gdm3 in the code from original post by terdon at U&L.

Three steps:

Guest folders under /tmp, under gdm3 non-password login is not allowed, so create a password with greater than 5 character in length.

`sudo useradd -d /tmp/guestx -p XXXXX guestx`

Create and edit some PostLogin and PostSession bash scripts in /etc/gdm3

(a) PostLogin script

create/edit

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/PostLogin/Default
```

and add

```bash
#!/bin/sh
guestuser="guestx" ## Next set up guest user session files/folders
if [[ "$USER" = "$guestuser" ]]; then
   mkdir /tmp/"$guestuser"
   cp /etc/skel/* /tmp/"$guestuser"
   chown -R "$guestuser":"$guestuser" /tmp/"$guestuser"
fi
exit 0
```

(b) PostSession script

create/edit

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default
```

and add

```bash
#!/bin/sh
guestuser="guestx" ## Next clear the guest user session files/folders
if [[ "$USER" = "$guestuser" ]]; then
   rm -rf /tmp/"$guestuser"
fi
exit 0
```

Make the above scripts executable:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/gdm3/PostLogin/Default /etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default
```

gdm3 does not allow no password logins, so set a password for this new guest user account. For those who do not know howto, take a look here:

https://people.gnome.org/~shaunm/mobile-mallard/gnome-help/user-addguest.html

CAUTION: I would suggest not check the 'Do not ask password at login', otherwise you will always boot into a guest session Lol :)

EDIT NOTE: edited the temp guest username from 'guest' to 'guestx' so as not to confuse from the default ubuntu guest username.

###################### UPDATE

For some reason on a new install/upgrades of/to Ubuntu 17.10, the tmpfs is not being deleted. The presession seems to work, suggest adding the following to `/etc/gdm3/PreSession/Default` folder:

`sudo nano /etc/gdm3/PreSession/Default`

add these lines after the last line:

```
guestuser="guestx"
if [[ "$USER" = "$guestuser" ]]; then
rm -rf /tmp/"$guestuser"
fi
```

Comment: You could just as easily rm -rf /home/guest what is the advantage of using tmp ? Also you did not address the fact that the old guest was locked down by apparmor, how did you address this ? I highly advise you use a kiosk specific distro, easier to deploy and more secure.

Comment: See http://porteus-kiosk.org/ or similar. many advantages to a kiosk spin ;)

Comment: I was looking at the tuxdiary. My concerns were more for people who would every once in a while like to loan their laptops or PCs. I did not follow your concern regarding apparmor. I had installed a clean Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 subsequently upgraded to 17.10, as I noticed gdm3 has a lot of issues (like no login randomly) thinking that 17.10 version of gdm3 would be better.

Comment: Well, as you know, physical access is root access so if you are loaning out your computer probably just make a regular account , call it what you will, and delete it afterwards. Just my 2c but your solution is a long run for a short slide. I guess my point is that your solution is a long way from the guest session locked down by apparmor . IMO that was the advantage of the guest session, the additional security features.

Comment: I agree on the apparmor part. In my solution, all the guest files will be hosted in tmpfs and simple logout clears it all.

Comment: I see that . I would hate you if you loaned me a computer and all my files were deleted on log out, lol.